# Java - Separate two gzip Strings

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I have two Strings. For example "apple" and "newton". I compress them using gzip separately and join the resultant gzipped strings and store in a file. Then I retrieve the content in the file. When I unzip the total string together I get the exact result. But I want to find the EOF of each gzipped String. Is this possible.

This is required because I store large junk of data. i retrieve using a buffer size. When I directly try to unzip I get EOFException. If I am able to get the EOF I can truncate the unwanted part and then unzip the required content

Answer (score 3):

Use any delimiting character before joining the two strings, for example a space or a comma, so that you can recognize the end of each string.

when you will unzip the total string together, you will get result like this "apple,newton",

Now use [split() method of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) class to get the individual strings.

```
String[] strings = totalString.split("," , 0);
```

Comment: I have tried this and its working. But its like is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store "apple", "newton" as two separate String objects with another object to separate this two. When you read object, you can compare what type of object. This way you can find separator object easily.

Answer (score 0):

The inflater has a method isFinished() which stops at boundaries. i basically wrote a class to extend the GzipinputStream and get back the inflater object. Whenever there is a part stream which is completed isFinished returns true. you can either continue reading or stop there